# python: allowing user to select multiple items from a list

Tags: python

Beginner here :)

Without using any GUIs like tkinter, is there a good way to allow a user to select multiple items from a list and show them which one(s) they have selected?

If I have `my_list` with 10 elements and I display them on the screen, I want the user to be able to select which one of those items they want and then make a new list with the chosen elements.

Edit: I was thinking about this more and thinking that I could show a list of items and highlight the selected choices with a different color. The user can use the spacebar to select multiple choices (if anyone has used the saml2aws utility, my thinking is similar to that). I don't know if there's a Python package that has something similar to that?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: instead of a list, have u tried using `dictionary`?

Comment: Would appreciate if you could mark an answer

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to use dictionaries, but you can use a normal list too.

If I understand correctly, you have a list and you will prompt users to choose elements from that list. then you want to do something with the chosen items from the list.

Here is a minimal example:

```
l = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
print(l)
n = int(input('number of items to choose?'))
chosed_items = []
while n > 0:
    chosed = input('choose item: ')
    if chosed in l and chosed not in chosed_items:
        chosed_items.append(chosed)
    n = n-1

# do something with the chosen items
print(chosed_items)
```

Comment: Here, if the user does not end up typing the exact same name as in the list, the code wont work. That is why i think, using numbers to mark, is a more efficient way from user POV

Comment: @CoolCloud this was a draft example. It's way far to be perfect of course. I mentioned already that using dictionaries would be better. I just gave a possibility here on how to work on this. It would be always better if the person who asked the question just gain ideas from us and then do further with his coding skills to improve himself too :)

Comment: i did not point out a mistake of yours(the code is absolutely minimal), on first thought when i did this, i got an empty list, so i was wondering what was wrong. So i thought u shud mention it in the answer, so the OP isnt confused too :D

Comment: that is why I wrote: here is a minimal example :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is something that would help you but I tried to make it quite minimal and clean. I basically just split at the users comma and check if each element is in a given list. If so it will be append to another list.
Make sure that when it asks for your input you do something like:
1,2,3
Then it will properly split at the comma.
Code:

```
list1 = ['1','2','3']
chosen = []
ask = (input(': '))
ask = ask.split(',')
for asks in ask:
    if asks in list1:
        chosen.append(asks)
print(chosen)
```